# Setting up a one to many relationship in Core Data on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, core-data

I am new to iPhone development trying to figure out how to setup a one to many relationship Core Data.  I have two Entities setup One Leagues which has a one to many relationship to an entity Teams.  So lot's of teams in a league.  Think all the teams that play baseball and are in the MLB.

I am pre-filling the data when the user first enter's their username and password, so I have the leagues populate first, which I have no problem with.  Then when I begin adding the teams I do a search looking for league.  Code is below.

```
- (NSMutableSet *)checkItem:(int *)identifier inTable:(NSString *)table inContext:(NSString *)context {

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:table inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:context,identifier];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *items = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    [fetchRequest release];

    if ([items count] >= 1) {
        return [items objectAtIndex:0];
    } else {
        return nil;
    }
}
```

By calling this and then set up the team entry and save ('league' is my relationship):

```
NSMutableSet *leagueObjectSet = [self checkItem:lid inTable:@"Leagues" inContext:@"id=%i"];

NSManagedObject *teamObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Teams" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

[teamObject setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:tid] forKey:@"id"];
[teamObject setValue:[dict valueForKey:@"name"] forKey:@"teamName"];
[teamObject setValue:leagueObjectSet forKey:@"league"];

[self saveAction];
```

When I run this I get this error message in the console.

"the entity Teams is not key value coding-compliant for the key "league"."

Am I doing this right?  With everything I have read it seems like I am.  I come from a MySQL background so be gentle!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description, I believe that you have a wrong setup for your one to many relationship. Assuming you have two entities named League and Team, and that you have correctly setup the relationship, when you want to relate a team to a league, your league object must not be a `NSMutableSet` as shown in your code snippet: it must be a `NSManagedObject` too. A League object, being on the to many side of the relationship will have a property named teams or similar which will be a `NSMutableSet`. A Team object, on the one side of the relationship will have instead a property named league or similar which is a League object.

Then, to setup the relationship you can do as you did using key value coding, but for performance reasons it is best to do

```
teamObject.id = yourId;
teamObject.teamName = @"your team name";
teamObject.league = yourLeagueObject;
```

This is much faster and suggested by Apple.

Comment: Thanks for chiming in, I have changed some stuff up but it still isn't working.  If I comment the "teamObject.league = yourLeagueObject;" out then it does write everything but doesn't make the relationship.  Error I get is "[Teams setLeague:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance"  

So my 'Leagues' Entity has a teams attribute, and the teams attribute has the To-Many checked.  And the inverse is set to league, which is the relationship attribute in the Teams Entity which doesn't have the To-Many checkbox checked.  

Is that correct?

Comment: http://designmenace.com/sample/leaguesEntity.png
http://designmenace.com/sample/teamsEntity.png

Comment: I got it.  Actually ended up being an issue in my XMLParser.  Traced it back and found that.  What you wrote helped a lot though.  Thanks!